# Support for Fulton reading (chap 3 and 5)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

I am studying on my own the book of the Fulton (algebraic curves). My goal is to get to chapter 5. I happen to encounter difficulties in two chapters, 3 and 5. So I would like to know if there is another book, lecture notes etc ... that can help me in parallel to the Fulton before these two chapters. My experience in algebraic geometry is very small. But I know that for example answers like: use the Hartshone, is a joke of bad taste. And I really would like some help (a more detailed text) to go through Fulton's Chapters 3 and 5.

Thanks

Comment: You can try : " Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach" by Garitty and al.